# GeneratorExit error in openai streaming in case of long response

Tags: python, streaming, fastapi, openai-api

when i ask question which are supposed to produce long answer, streaming api breaks. and got this error `GeneratorExit`. This usually happend when response is greater then 250 tokens.
Here is my code

```
from langsmith.run_helpers import traceable
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

app = FastAPI()
```

```
def call_openai_streaming(client,  messages):
    final_response = ""
    openai_stream = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-4",
        messages=messages,
        stream=True
    )

    for chunk in openai_stream:
        if chunk.choices[0].delta.content is not None:
            final_response += chunk.choices[0].delta.content
            yield chunk.choices[0].delta.content
```

```
def qa_conversation(request):
    # (Your existing qa_conversation function with modifications)
    messages = [
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": request.system_message,
        },
        {"role": "user", "content": request.user_message},
    ]
    @traceable(run_type="chain", name=f"qa_conversation")
    def llm_call(messages):
        client = OpenAI(
            timeout=httpx.Timeout(600.0, read=60.0, write=60.0, connect=60.0),
        )
        
        yield from call_openai_streaming(
            client,
            messages,
        )
      
    return llm_call(messages)
```

```
@app.post("/generate_assistant_response")
def assistant_response(request: Request):
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Connection": "Transfer-Encoding",
    }
   
    generator = qa_conversation(request)
    return StreamingResponse(generator, media_type="text/plain", headers=headers)
```